# PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting '-' or identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli, php5

Buen día.
Tengo un problema,me sucede que al tratar de realizar esta consulta de **MySQL** en **PHP** me sale este error:

> PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting '-' or identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING)

Aquí mi código:

```php
require 'Smarty/libs/Smarty.class.php';
    require 'conexion.php';

    $smarty = new Smarty;

    $upd=("SELECT * FROM RegistroPromedio WHERE Id LIKE ".$_POST['Id'].""); 

    $dato=mysqli_fetch_array($upd);

            if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
            $qry=("UPDATE RegistroPromedio SET 
                nombre='.$_POST['nombre'].'
                ,apellido='.$_POST['apellido'].'
                ,edad='.$_POST['edad'].'
                ,TipoId='.$_POST['TipoId'].
                ,Id='.$_POST['Id'].'
                ,salario='.$_POST['salario'].'");

        header('Location:index.php');

    }
var_dump($qry);


    $smarty->assign('users',$dato);
    $smarty->display("templates/edit.html");
```

Agradezco si me pueden ayudar.

Comment: te has engalletado con las comillas simples y dobles : https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE , el error aparece por tener $_POST ( un array ) sin llaves dentro de un string de comillas dobles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solucionado usando una comilla simple y una doble antes de cada $_POST o $_GET asi mismo al cerrarlos

```php
<?php

    require 'Smarty/libs/Smarty.class.php';
    require 'conexion.php';

    $smarty = new Smarty;

    $Id=$_POST['Id'];

    $upd=("SELECT * FROM RegistroPromedio WHERE Id = ".$Id.""); 
    $datos = $db->getAll($upd);


            if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

            $qry=("UPDATE RegistroPromedio SET Nombre= '".$_POST['nombre']."',Apellido='".$_POST['apellido']."',Edad='".$_POST['edad']."',TipoId='".$_POST['TipoId']."',Id='".$_POST['Id']."',Salario='".$_POST['salario']."' WHERE Id=$Id");

            $up=$db->Execute($qry);

            header()

    }

    $smarty->assign('users',$dato);
    $smarty->assign("update",$db->Execute($qry));
    $smarty->display("templates/edit.html");
 ?>
```